# Java Version Comparison

Tags: java, versioning

I am trying to understand the Java versioning scheme and having difficulty finding a direct definite answer online. I am having two versions of java, and want to know which one is greater:

When doing `java -version` I will receive:

```
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
```

If I am trying to determine if this version is greater than `JDK 7u131`; how would I make this comparison? Is `u` for `update` and `b` for `build`, does that make a difference?

Comment: `147 > 131`. Java 7 is end of life, though.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/versioning-naming-139433.html

Comment: From Java 9 you can start doing: `System.out.println(Runtime.version());` (on my machine it prints: 9+181) - very easy to parse the version/build from that string.

Comment: Java recommends not parsing as you are now and assuming 1.X - as this will all change.  In fact it should go from 1.8 -> 9 -> 18.3 if their new naming scheme holds.

Comment: @purringpigeon is correct. To learn more: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223

Comment: There's a [version parser](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-alpn-agent/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mortbay/jetty/alpn/agent/JavaVersion.java) in the jetty alpn agent.